# Replace the matched selections from another file

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3

I'm doing the multi-language translation job,

As you can see, the right document should be replaced with the left document if they are matched.

[image: inline]

How could I do it with Sublime text?

Because they are not 1-1 mapping

## My expected result is

[image: inline]

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a proof of concept that allows you to replace matched selections between a **source** *( left )* & **target** *( right )* file.

## DEMO:

[image: Demo]

---

---

## USAGE:

To use MatchReplace:

- copy the plugin folder to your `Packages` directory
- edit the `replacementKeys` array in the `run` function to suit your match+replace needs
- save the plugin & restart SublimeText
- open a 2-group window layout using <kbd>Shift + Alt + 2</kbd>
- move the document you want as the SOURCE to the left group
- move the document you want to MATCH with the source to the right group
- open the Command Palette with <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + P</kbd> and run the `Match Replace: Demo` command

#### Note:

`replacementKeys` must be an **exact** match at both documents *( leading whitespace is ignored )*.

If you want to allow for variation within the `replacementKeys`, you will need to implement an additional layer of `RegEx` processing.

---

---

## Implementation:

- get active views of each group in a 2 group window
- find `RegEx` matches of a user-defined array of keys which will be matched at both documents
- store value regions of both documents, and string values of the source document
- sort stored values by region
- iterate over regions at the target document, replacing all matched values from the source

The demo is written to work with single tier `JSON` files, but can be adjusted as necessary.

`RegEx` patterns to precede & follow `replacementKeys` are:

- `queryPrefix`
- `querySuffix`

---

---

## CODE:

The script works a bit more smoothly with a custom `Edit` module of mine, so I recommend that you download the entire plugin here:

## [@ GitHub](https://github.com/Enteleform/-SCRIPTS-/tree/master/SublimeText/%5BMisc%5D/%5BProof%20Of%20Concept%5D%20MatchReplace)

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin
import Edit
import operator

class MatchReplaceDemoCommand ( sublime_plugin.TextCommand ):

    def run ( self, edit ):

        replacementKeys = []

        #■■■  Populate With Keys To Be Replaced In Document2  ■■■#
        replacementKeys.append ( "flight_number" )
        replacementKeys.append ( "price" )
        replacementKeys.append ( "payment" )

        self.replace_KeyValues ( replacementKeys )

    def replace_KeyValues ( self, replacementKeys ):

        window = self.view.window()

        document1_ResultStrings = {}
        document2_ResultRegions = {}

        #■■■  Verify : 2 Active Window Groups  ■■■#
        windowGroup_Count = window.num_groups()

        if windowGroup_Count != 2:
            return

        #■■■  Set : Document Views  ■■■#
        document1 = window.active_view_in_group ( 0 ) # Document 1 == SOURCE
        document2 = window.active_view_in_group ( 1 ) # Document 2 == MATCH
        edit = Edit.get ( document2 )

        #■■■  Set : Seach Parameters  ■■■#
        query_StartPosition = 0
        queryPrefix         = "((^)|(^[\t\ ]+))"
        querySuffix         = ":"

        #■■■  Store : KeyValue Regions & Strings  ■■■#
        for key in replacementKeys:

            #■■■  Find Document1 Key Regions & Strings  ■■■#
            document1_KeyRegion          = document1.find ( queryPrefix + key + querySuffix, query_StartPosition )
            document1_ResultRegion_Start = document1_KeyRegion.b
            document1_ResultRegion_End   = document1.line ( document1_KeyRegion ).b
            document1_ResultRegion       = sublime.Region ( document1_ResultRegion_Start, document1_ResultRegion_End )
            document1_ResultString       = document1.substr ( document1_ResultRegion )

            #■■■  Find Document2 Key Regions  ■■■#
            document2_KeyRegion          = document2.find ( queryPrefix + key + querySuffix, query_StartPosition )
            document2_ResultRegion_Start = document2_KeyRegion.b
            document2_ResultRegion_End   = document2.line ( document2_KeyRegion ).b
            document2_ResultRegion       = sublime.Region ( document2_ResultRegion_Start, document2_ResultRegion_End )

            #■■■  Verify Match  ■■■#
            if  document1_ResultRegion_Start != -1 \
            and document2_ResultRegion_Start != -1:
                document1_ResultStrings[ key ] = document1_ResultString
                document2_ResultRegions[ key ] = document2_ResultRegion

        #■■■  Verify : Matches Found  ■■■#
        if len ( document1_ResultStrings ) == 0 \
        or len ( document2_ResultRegions ) == 0:
            return

        #■■■  Sort Regions To Avoid Replacement Overlap  ■■■#
        document2_ResultRegions = sorted ( document2_ResultRegions.items(), key=operator.itemgetter ( 1 ) )

        #■■■  Replace Matched KeyValues  ■■■#
        for key, value  in reversed ( document2_ResultRegions ):
            replacementField  = key
            replacementRegion = value
            replacementString = document1_ResultStrings[ key ]
            edit.replace ( replacementRegion, replacementString )
```